# Netbean IDE 7.3 create empty file

Tags: netbeans, ide

i dunno whether i did not try to find this empty file{*IM NOT talking about java empty file} properly or what.

I was following a tutorial on Netbean platform. the tutorial is asking to create an EMPTY file in an java application project.

i try to right click on the Sources Package. and choose other and i go tru each of the options file group given but I DIDNT manage to find Empty file

[image: trying to find the empty file]

i also pressed the F1 button to get the help doc, i search on Empty file, i found the description on it. but i didnt manage to find how to create it.

im sorry for the stupid question. but i really want to know how!

Answer (score 1):

Try Other in Categories and there should be empty file type